# How to register tybelib(.tlb) file in ole/COM object viewer?

Tags: visual-studio, com

**Background:**
I have created a COM C++ project without using visual studio ATL template.I have registered the dll in registory editor. I'm able to locate the registered dll in registry editor, but i'm not able to loacte the typelib(.tlb) file in OLE/COM viewer. Projects created with ATL template visual studio are found in both registry editor and OLE/COM viewer.

**I want to know:**
where to search for the .tlb in OLE/COM viewer?
or
Is there any additional steps to be done to register .tlb?

**I want to know this beacuse:**
I tried to add the above COM dll as reference to the c# project.
so i went to add references, searched through COM tab in reference manager,
only .tlb files registered in OLE/COM viewer were shown in tab.

**About COM project I created:**
Created a win32 C++ dll project.
I created .idl file compiled and generated **h.h,**i.c,**c.c,dlldata.c files.
Then, included derived class for the interface in .idl and class factory to generate instance of class
Then, included DllGetClassObject, DllCanUnloadNow, DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer functions and exported with .def file.

I created a C++ client and imported the typelib called the functions of the above COM  project.It worked fine.

**Problem**
I tried to add the above COM dll as reference to the c# project.
so i went to add references, searched through COM tab in reference manager,
only .tlb files registered in OLE/COM viewer were shown in tab.

Comment: Your DllRegisterServer() function doesn't do what it needs to do.  Very easy to get it wrong when you don't understand proper registration yet.  We can't see it from here, you'll have to show us.

Comment: I have registered :In CLSID  {3B1B067B-8212-4BFC-9186-49ED5D222D45} InProcServer32 and progId.Can you tell me what else to be registered?

Comment: So you don't know what it needs to do and you don't want our help to help you get it fixed.  Pretty unconstructive way to use this web site, hard to see the point.  Best to find help at Google instead, an obvious query is "what registry keys need to be written to register a com server".  First hit is good.